# Dynamic notification for my android app

Tags: android, google-play, android-debug

I would like to set dynamic notification  for my app. For E.g if 4 of my app installed in four of my friend mobile. They have to hear my voice "Amir"(as notification that was recorded by me and it should store in my app while i install) when i send a message to them within my app.

Comment: have you consider using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

Comment: Yes, But the receiver should hear my name(as notification) instead of default notification .

Comment: hmmm in my opinion i think you'll be better off with broadcastreceiver try researching for Android Interprocess Definition Language (AIDL) that might give you some idea to better implement your needs

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit more consuming to play a recorded voice globally on all 4 devices . For doing this you will need some server integration.

But other wise if you simply wish to read out AMIR or any other other text to your users, to notify them, you can use GCM and TEXT2SPEECH engine as a feedback system. in onReceive method on BroadCast Receiver of your GCM, simply read out the content passed to it using TEXT@SPEECH ENGINE of Andriod.

By the way I generally like this idea, but I think any user will not like his phone speaking out different things when he is asleep or in a meeting or..

So be careful using this.
CHeers!